# Spring Boot WebFlux - Объединение полученных объектов

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Прошу подсказать - как я могу собрать объект, части которого я реактивно получаю разными запросами. Т.е. первым запросом мы получаем Flex со следующим содержимым:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "...",
        "barId": 1
    },
    {
        "foo": "...",
        "barId": 2
    }
]
```

Вторым:

```
[
    {
        "barId": 1,
        "data": "..."
    },
    {
        "barId": 2,
        "data": "..."
    }
]
```

Как это можно объединить во Flex или объект следующей структуры?

```
[
    {
        "foo": "...",
        "bar": {
            "barId": 1,
            "data": "..."
        }
    },
    {
        "foo": "...",
        "bar": {
            "barId": 2,
            "data": "..."
        }
    }
]
```